# Process exits upon reading from pipe

Tags: c, pipe, posix

I have a pipe, a parent and a child process. The parent reads from a file some data, puts it into the pipe, and afterwards, the child should read all the data. My problem is this: my parent reads the data, the child receives the data from the pipe, but when it reaches its end, the process just exits, and no output after exiting the while instruction, as it should have.

```
int main(void)
{
    int inputFile, channel[2], PID;
    if(-1 == pipe(channel))
    {
        perror("Eroare");
        return 0;
    }
    if(-1 == (inputFile = open("data.txt", O_RDONLY)))
    {
        perror("Error");
        return 0;
    }
    if(-1 == (PID = fork()))
    {
        perror("Error");
        return 0;
    }
    if(PID != 0)
    {
        char buffer;
        if(-1 == close(channel[0]))
            perror("Error");
        while(1 == read(inputFile, &buffer, 1))
            write(channel[1], &buffer, 1);
        if(-1 == close(channel[1]))
            perror("Error");
    }
    else
    {
        char buffer;
        while(1 == read(channel[0], &buffer, 1))
            printf("%c\n", buffer);
        if(-1 == close(channel[0]))
            perror("Error");
        if(-1 == close(channel[1]))
            perror("Error");
        printf("Should output this");       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My data file contains the string: `ABC` and the output is:

```
A
B
C
```

+ 2 extra empty lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read blocks if there are still other writers for that file descriptor. While you did close the file descriptor the parent had, the child's file descriptor is still open and will only be closed after the read return something other than 1. However, the read will block, since the child process itself is considered a writer.

To fix this, just move the call to close the write end before you start reading like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int inputFile, channel[2], PID;
    if(-1 == pipe(channel))
    {
        perror("Eroare");
        return 0;
    }
    if(-1 == (inputFile = open("data.txt", O_RDONLY)))
    {
        perror("Error");
        return 0;
    }
    if(-1 == (PID = fork()))
    {
        perror("Error");
        return 0;
    }
    if(PID != 0)
    {
        char buffer;
        if(-1 == close(channel[0]))
            perror("Error");
        while(1 == read(inputFile, &buffer, 1))
            write(channel[1], &buffer, 1);
        if(-1 == close(channel[1]))
            perror("Error");
    }
    else
    {
        char buffer;
        if(-1 == close(channel[1]))
            perror("Error");
        while(1 == read(channel[0], &buffer, 1))
            printf("%c\n", buffer);
        if(-1 == close(channel[0]))
            perror("Error");
        printf("Should output this");       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, only your main process was exiting, the child lived on as an orphaned process, forever stuck at that call to read.

Comment: But what if I want to write something in the child to the pipe, and after make parent `wait(NULL)` for the child, so as for the parent to read from the pipe what the child has written?

Comment: If you want the child to keep the write side of the pipe open, then you cannot simply read from the pipe until the pipe is closed.  You'll need some other mechanism for the parent to inform the child that it has written all of the data.